# Is it not possible to search by Id field with SOSL?

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, sosl, search

Why can't I do this?

```
FIND "0Hn8A00000093AvSAI" IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Name, Id)
```

If I put a part of the *Name* of the contact with that ID, I get that contact back.
But when I put the ID there, no results.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: if you have id, then why you need SOSL? 
`SELECT ID, name from Contact where id='0Hn8A00000093AvSAI'` shall work

Comment: @YsrShk I don't want to know what I have :) I was hoping the user could get the record as a search result even when they input the id

Answer (score 4):

Id fields don't get search indexed, only various types of text fields, like Name and Phone. You can, however, use an ID as part of the filter:

```
FIND {sometext} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Name WHERE Id = :someId)
```

But, of course, if you don't know any possible text, that won't help you.

You'll want to vote on this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLtAAI) to have a retrieve call, which would be ideal. You can use the REST API to get the values back, if you're in a position to use a callout.

Answer (score 1):

[SOSL searches text fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm):

> You can search text, email, and phone fields for multiple objects, including custom objects, that you have access to in a single query in the following environments.

Use SOQL to search on Ids